# Restrict Pan Responder Movement in React Native

Tags: react-native

Hi I am creating a React Native App and using PanResponder in it. Everything works fine but I want to restrict the movement of element to always stay inside the screen. At the moment if we swipe horizontally or vertically, it goes outside the screen.

Here is my code

```
class CourseEditScreen extends Component{

constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  gestureState: {},
  thumbSize: width + 20,
  thumbHeight: height,
  left: width / 2,
  top: height / 2
}
}

componentWillMount() {
console.log('componentWillMount...');
this.gestureResponder = createResponder({
  onStartShouldSetResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onStartShouldSetResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetResponder: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: (evt, gestureState) => true,

  onResponderGrant: (evt, gestureState) => {
  },
  onResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {

    let thumbSize = this.state.thumbSize;
    let thumbHeight = this.state.thumbHeight;
    if (gestureState.pinch && gestureState.previousPinch) {
      thumbSize *= (gestureState.pinch / gestureState.previousPinch);
      thumbHeight *= (gestureState.pinch / gestureState.previousPinch);
    }

    let {left, top} = this.state;

    left += (gestureState.moveX - gestureState.previousMoveX);
    top += (gestureState.moveY - gestureState.previousMoveY);

    this.setState({
      gestureState: {
        ...gestureState
      },
      left, top, thumbSize, thumbHeight
    })
  },
  onResponderTerminationRequest: (evt, gestureState) => true,
  onResponderRelease: (evt, gestureState) => {
    this.setState({
      gestureState: {
        ...gestureState
      }
    })
  },
  onResponderTerminate: (evt, gestureState) => {
  },
  onResponderSingleTapConfirmed: (evt, gestureState) => {
    console.log('onResponderSingleTapConfirmed...' + JSON.stringify(gestureState));
  },
  debug: true
});
}
render() {
  const thumbSize = this.state.thumbSize;
  const thumbHeight = this.state.thumbHeight;
  return(
    <View style={{flex: 1,}} {...this.gestureResponder}>
       <Image
      style={{ flex:1, position: 'absolute', width: thumbSize, height: thumbHeight, left: this.state.left - thumbSize/2, top: this.state.top - thumbHeight/2,}}
      source={{ uri: this.props.navigation.state.params.PhotoURL }}
      resizeMode="cover"
      pointerEvents='none'
      />
    </View>
  )
  }
  }
```

PS: I am new to React Native and I have used this code from a demo. Everything here is working as intended except I want the Image to not go outside of the screen while scrolling.

Comment: So the thing controlling how the image moves is the onResponderMove. There you are( or the demo is) calculating left and top for the image depending on the gesture. All you have to do is check if the left value is outside your threshold or not. I don't want to post code since you are new and trying it out will be better for learning but if you would rather have me post code I'll gladly do it.

Comment: Did you figure out a great way to do this?